# Response of a regular expression search Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

i'm trying to get to work a python script which should match a regular expression, the object producted by the much is always an empty string so i think i'm using regular expression without the needed knowledge. Can someone help? Below is the code:

```
def storecheck(text, store):
res =""
for line in text.splitlines():
    print str(store)
    if re.search('/'+str(store)+',/g', line):
        print re.search('/'+str(store)+',/g', line)+';'
        res+= line
        return res
```

'store' has the value of an integer in the script.
I've read the manuals of re.match and re.search in the official site of python, but this regexp should match as long as the [online tester](http://regex101.com) aren't all an illusion. so anyone sees what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not put `store = str(store)` at the top of the function so you don't keep calling it?

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't need delimiters... and if you want a global search, you would use `re.findall`. Maybe you intend to do something like that?

```
def storecheck(text, store):
res = ""
for line in text.splitlines():
    print str(store)
    if re.search(str(store), line):
        print ';'.join(re.findall(str(store), line))
        res += line
        return res
```

I'm still quite new to python myself though; there could be a much better way to do the same thing.